# *.c not rebult when dependency x.h changed, using auto-generated *.d file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am facing one issue while handling dependency files during compilation. I am just giving you the scenario which I faced in my project.

I have two C source files called `a.c`, `b.c` which includes one header file called `c.h`. I ran makefile which has instructions to compile both files. I can successfully compile the `a.c` file, but I have seen some failures while comping `b.c` which requires to do some changes in `c.h` to fix that issue. After I made change in `c.h` and trigger build (incremental build) the `a.c` file should compile again, too, right? Because `a.c` also depends on the `c.h` file.

I followed all dependency mechanism (creating auto dependency files & including `.d` files, etc)

```
DEPSALL := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $(TGTFILES)/*.c)))
-include $(DEPSALL)
$(TGTFILES)/%.o: $(TGTFILES)/%.c
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        $(CC64) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $@)) -o $(@) -c $(CFLAGS64) $<
  ...
  ...
```

Am I missing something here? I want to rebuild all the `.c` files which are including the particular header file which I changed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use `$(wildcard $(TGTFILES)/*.d)` instead of your complicated first line? And `$(TGTFILES)/$*.d` instead of `$(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $@))` in your recipe? And what is your default goal (it is not part of the part of the Makefile you show)?

Comment: Is there any difference in using 'wildcard' function against my way of assigning DEPSALL variable ? I am new to make i want to know that.   Yes ,default goal is not in the part of makfile which i shown above.

Comment: You can a the line `$(info $(DEPSALL))` to see what that variable contains, and verify that it contains `a.d`. You can examine `a.d` to verify that it contains `a.o: c.h`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet:  The point of using these compilicated patsubst+basename invokations is to put all the .d files in the current directory instead of in `$(TGTFILES)`.  Of course, *why* the OP wants to do that is a mystery.  More commonly, you want them in the same directory as the .o files (which is the default for -MMD -- no need for an extra -MF option).

Comment: @ChrisDodd: nor sure of that: `basename` keeps the directory part. It only removes the suffix part.

Comment: @santosh: there is a difference: your way is far more complicated and difficult to understand. Computing `$(TGTFILES)/*.d` with `$(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $(TGTFILES)/*.c))`is really strange, don't you think? Unless you think it does something else?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: `basename` removes the directory part.  Indeed, as used here, that is ALL it does -- with no second argument it does not remove any suffix.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: aren't you mixing up the `make` `basename` function and the `basename` shell utility? Have a look, maybe, to the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, No you are wrong. It wont keep .d files in current working directory.. I will keep them in $(TGTFILES) path. Which has .o files. You can cross-check the GNUmanual patsubs function for the same.

Comment: @santosh: I never claimed that the `.d` files would be kept in the current directory. You probably wanted to answer Chris Dodd who indeed claimed that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete: you do not really describe the problem you are facing (but we can probably guess that object files are not rebuilt while they should) and the part of the Makefile you show is not sufficient to understand what your goals are.

Anyway, first of all, this expression:

```
DEPSALL := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $(TGTFILES)/*.c)))
```

is uselessly complex. It is equivalent to the much simpler and easier to understand:

```
DEPSALL := $(wildcard $(TGTFILES)/*.d))
```

Similarly, in your compilation recipe you can replace:

```
$(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $@))
```

by:

```
$(TGTFILES)/$*.d
```

But let's go back to your main problem (at least what I guess is your main problem): when modifying your header file, some object files are not rebuilt while they should.

My guess is that you think:

```
DEPSALL := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $(TGTFILES)/*.c)))
```

will assign to `DEPSALL` a list of dependency files, one per source file, like this other form would do:

```
DEPSALL := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(wildcard $(TGTFILES)/*.c))
```

If this is what you think, then you are wrong. Your version will assign to `DEPSALL` the list of dependency files that **currently exist** in `$(TGTFILES)` when you invoke make. If some (or all) are missing, some object files will not be rebuilt...

I suggest that you carefully read [this excellent post about Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/#noreexec). If you adapt it to your set-up, you should end up with something like:

```
TGTFILES := tgtfiles
SRCS     := $(wildcard $(TGTFILES)/*.c)
OBJS     := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))
DEPS     := $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(SRCS))
INCLUDES := include
CFLAGS   += -I$(INCLUDES)

.PHONY: objs clean

objs: $(OBJS)

%.o: %.c
%.o: %.c %.d
    $(CC) -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $*.Td $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
    @mv -f $*.Td $*.d && touch $@

%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: %.d

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS)

include $(DEPS)
```

Several aspects may look strange, useless or even completely wrong. But if you carefully read the above mentioned post you will see that it perfectly makes sense. Demo:

```
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── include
│   └── c.h
└── tgtfiles
    ├── a.c
    └── b.c

2 directories, 4 files
$ make
cc -MT tgtfiles/b.o -MMD -MP -MF tgtfiles/b.Td -Iinclude  -c -o tgtfiles/b.o tgtfiles/b.c
cc -MT tgtfiles/a.o -MMD -MP -MF tgtfiles/a.Td -Iinclude  -c -o tgtfiles/a.o tgtfiles/a.c
$ tree
.
├── Makefile
├── include
│   └── c.h
└── tgtfiles
    ├── a.c
    ├── a.d
    ├── a.o
    ├── b.c
    ├── b.d
    └── b.o

2 directories, 8 files
$ cat tgtfiles/a.d
tgtfiles/a.o: tgtfiles/a.c include/c.h

include/c.h:
$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'objs'.
$ touch include/c.h 
$ make
cc -MT tgtfiles/b.o -MMD -MP -MF tgtfiles/b.Td -Iinclude  -c -o tgtfiles/b.o tgtfiles/b.c
cc -MT tgtfiles/a.o -MMD -MP -MF tgtfiles/a.Td -Iinclude  -c -o tgtfiles/a.o tgtfiles/a.c
```

Answer (score 0):

`wildcard` function application doesn't look right. Should probably be:

```
DEPSALL := $(patsubst %,%.d,$(basename $(wildcard $(TGTFILES)/*.c)))
```

Comment: This is what I initially thought but I am not sure of that. The original version expands as the list of `.d` files in the `$(TGTFILES)` directory, which is probably the right thing. Why the OP did not simply use `$(wildcard $(TGTFILES)/*.d)` is a mystery to me but his version works.